# the negation of $\preceq$

Tags: xetex, symbols, amsmath

How do I type a modification of this
$\npreccurlyeq$ symbol with **not** negated the above symbol, just negated the bottom one ?

Please note that I need the bottom part of the 2 symbols aligned with he curved upper part:
it should not be straight.

Also I need both version of it: the curved single and double lines (so all of them negated).
[image]

Comment: Clarification question: what exactly would be the meaning of these symbols? Aren't there other symbols available for such meanings? For example "smaller, but not equal" would just be `<`.

Comment: @Marijn You are right, I need them just for pleasing my eye, in fact. And also for my curiosity if this could be done. The meaning may lie in the cooperative game theory.

Comment: As far as I know, the requested symbol does not exist; an appropriate name (it it did exist) would be `\precncurlyeq`.  For best results, it should be (re)drawn based on the existing symbols that it is to accompany.  (See also my comment on the answer by Sebastiano.)

Comment: This symbol appears in `txfonts`, `mathabx`, and `MnSymbol`. The non-negated symbol also appears in `fdsymbol`, `boisik`, and `stix`. Since the symbol needs to be created from an existing symbol, the font you plan to use is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this using `-` it has been created the command `\undernegpreccurlyeq`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nback}[1][-.95pt]{
  \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$\rotatebox[origin=c]{-315}{\scaleobj{0.55}{-}}$}}
}
\newcommand{\undernegpreccurlyeq}{%
\mathrel{\ooalign{$\preccurlyeq$\cr\kern1.2pt$\nback$}}}
\begin{document}
$\preccurlyeq, \undernegpreccurlyeq, a \undernegpreccurlyeq b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum on request from the user*: You can use "for negated double line" the `=` symbol with a new symbol named `\underdnegccurlyeq`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nwback}[1][-.8pt]{
  \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$\rotatebox[origin=c]{-310}{\scaleobj{0.55}{=}}$}}
}
\newcommand{\underdnegccurlyeq}{%
\mathrel{\ooalign{$\preccurlyeq$\cr\kern2pt$\nwback$}}}
\begin{document}
$\preccurlyeq, \underdnegccurlyeq, a \underdnegccurlyeq b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although these look quite nice, I believe the orientation of the slash should be from right-to-left, not from left-to-right.  Although I don't understand the difference in meaning, when I was researching the STIX symbols collection, I encountered an article where there were three distinct negations: backslash, vertical, forward slash.  The traditional use of the forward slash to represent ordinary negation is, therefore, what I believe to be the preferred shape.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hi I totally accept your comment. When I write in the board the symbol \notin for example the negation bar is from right to left. I had created the code before I went to sleep. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sebastiano Looks great. Do you please also have an advice for negated **double line** as in your $$a\preceq b$$. I do not know even the unnegated case for this double line. Also, isn't there a LaTeX comman rather than TeX primitive for all of these ?

Comment: @user2925716 I hope to have understood your request adding another example. I suggest to read the comments of  barbara beeton and  Sandy G. Your symbols not exist and it is necessary **(re)drawn based on the existing symbols**.

Comment: @Sebastiano You have actually doubled the other (wrong) symbol.Keep it but please add doubling the other one.

Comment: @user2925716 Very kind, could you please draw it by hand so I can create the symbol you like? Otherwise, I don't understand. Excuse me.

Comment: @Sebastiano Why do you mean that I'm kind ? Hopefully it wasn't a joke meaning the opposite :-) Please see the edit this is the best I could achieve without having a scanner.

Comment: @user2925716 I don't often understand English and without your image I wouldn't have understood anything. In my opinion you could ask another question and post the link to this question. I think it is very difficult as I would have to use trimclip and I am not very expert in cropping.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your interest. Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591592/a-weired-sign-not-in-amssymb).

Comment: @user2925716 I have seen and I have upvoted you :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano That's nice of you, I thought it was you :-) Please try what you know, it is so little used that it is not included in the entire `amsmath` !

Comment: @user2925716 I'm seeing into the documentation of symbols-a4 but the symbol not exists. It is necessary to built it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Do not hurry, I will wait.